# Shrink CentOS VMDK on VMWare ESXi

Tags: centos, vmware, esxi, vmdk

I am trying to deploy an OVA based application which uses CentOS as base image. The recommended size of the application is 128 GB however, for some bizarre reason the expanded vmdk size is 502 GB.

I don't have much space in my ESXi host and therefore I have to shutdown a few hosts to get it working (so I noticed). I want to reduce the size of the disk to 130 GBs and free up the rest for other systems to use.

How can I achieve that?

```
ESXi Version: 6.7.0 (Build 8169922)
CentOS Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-305.7.1.el8_4.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either thin or shrink the vmdk.  It is possible that you need to zero some deleted blocks before doing so.  See https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002019 for guidance.